# What is the optimal way to represent letters for deep net?

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec

If I have to represent a word **sky**, I can assign each letter its number in the alphabet or an eigen-vector with 1 at i-th place, where i is letter number in the alphabet.

I don't much like first approach, because letters *a* and *b* don't correlate as 1 to 2. Second approach, on the other hand, makes an average word repsentation way too high-dimensional.

Use-case: trying to teach deep net to predict word's part-of-speech in a morphologically rich language.

Which of the approaches should I follow?

**Update.** Found some related info in a group I am subscribed to: https://offbit.github.io/how-to-read/

Answer (score 3):

A typical way is to assign to each character a vector, which is randomly initialized and learnt jointly with the rest of the network during the training phase. Example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475